# "edit page" not loading

Tags: performance, fatal-error

This has been happening for the last few days...

1. Click on edit page.
2. The page turns white, the loading bar starts moving and it looks like it's making progress based on this.
3. By about half way along, the loading bar gives up and the page stays on white.

I've looked up other responses to similar things and tried everything I can find:

- Switched the theme to 2019 default
- Bypassed all plugins
- Reset cache

Nothing has made a difference. Has anybody found any alternative solution to this problem?

Comment: This is usually called [White Screen of Death](https://wordpress.org/support/article/common-wordpress-errors/#the-white-screen-of-death) and you need to debug this further. Deactivating plugins and switching to a default theme is a good start. Activate all the logs you have, maybe even ask your hoster for more and there you'll get answers

Comment: Ah I see! I'm currently running cloudflare. Is it possible this could affect the situation?

Comment: It could, but I highly doubt it. Actually, CF should rather give you a error from their end. You can deactivate their magic and only use it as a DNS to rule any CF tools out